# Coded UI Test Generator has trouble correctly recording actions on a ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, coded-ui-tests

I'm currently working on making an application CUIT-Generator ready. That means that, as an example, I'm adding XAML setters to the styles for `DataGridRow` that set `Automation.ID` and `AutomationName`. Works just fine.

Now my issue is that there is a `ListView` where the `ItemTemplate` contains a `DataTemplate` which in turn has a custom UI control.

When recording any action on the text controls inside the custom UI control,  it only grabs the custom UI control and the hierarchy below it, but it doesn't record that it is inside a `ListView` and a `ListViewItem`.

Due to this, the control can not be found during test execution or when selecting the control in the UIMap and clicking `Search UI control`.

I tried setting the AutomationID/Name on the `ListViewItem` and the `ListView` but that does not have an impact on the recorded hierarchy.

XAML code for the `ListView`:

```
<ListView x:Name="sampleControl" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableCollectionOfViewModelItems}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Binding Path="AutoID"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Binding Path="AutoID"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <SampleNamespace:CustomUIControlView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code for the `CustomUIControlView`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SampleNamespace.CustomUIControlView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Border BorderThickness="3">
        <Expander>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name="SampleBox1" Height="20" Margin="5" Text="{Binding SampleProp1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="SampleBox2" Height="20" Margin="5" Text="{Binding SampleProp2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="SampleBox3" Height="20" Margin="5" Text="{Binding SampleProp3, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Name="SampleBox4" Height="20" Margin="5" Text="{Binding SampleProp4, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </Grid>
        </Expander>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

The recorded hierarchy for an action recorded on `SampleBox1` looks like this:

```
SampleAppWindow
---- CustomUIControlView
-------- Expander
------------ SampleBox1/TextBox
```

Obviously none of the controls, aside from the `Window` are going to be found.

I know that I could transfer the recorded actions to C# code and then edit the hierarchy and search properties myself but I would like to avoid doing this as I would have to remember doing that every time a `ListView` is involved in a recorded test.

I'm mentioning this as most solutions here on SO or on other websites come down to working around the problem like that.

This is on Visual Studio 2017 15.3.5 and .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Comment: To understand the structure better from Coded UI's point of view you could do a recursive descent (by calling `GetChildren()`) starting from the smallest item that the generator can properly identify. At each found control write a summary to a text file. However, the question mentions a "custom control" and they need to be written to support Coded UI. They need to have the correct UIA or MSAA interfaces so that Coded UI can interact with them. Ask the authors or suppliers of that Custom Control about what level of support it has for Coded UI, MSAA and UIA.

Comment: @AdrianHHH the custom control was created by us, and the CUIT-Generator can identify it and the controls inside of it. The problem is the ListView -> ListViewItem -> Custom control as ItemTemplate chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you are asking for something beyond what the CodedUi Code Generator can handle.

I would point out from the generated object structure it missed entirely the `ListView`. The route I would recommend is first being sure you can locate the `ListView`, generated or your own code, probably call `DrawHighlight` to be sure. I get your trying to avoid your own code for defining object definitions but it is probably only feasible to write your own.

Now specifically for your `CustomUIControlView`, I would urge you to define a matching `CodedUI` object that matches it. As is, an `Expander` with 4 children `TextBoxes`. This would cut down coding this definition several times. If you look at the generated code as examples to write these.

Depending on your view on designer files, you could also declare the immediately expected parent node of your `ListView` or itself as a partial class to hook in these unmatched children elements in a separate file to avoid it getting wiped by the generator. Then you would only need to update the designer file with the small `partial` statement edits.

Comment: I fear you may be correct in your assessment about the limitations of the CUIT-Generator. However, I want to be sure that I didn't make a mistake somewhere along the way that can be fixed. Maybe some property needs to be set or maybe it's possible to force the CUIT-Generator to include certain elements in a hierarchy.
The ListView itself is found - I added it via the target indicator to the UI tree and when told to identify the control, it was properly identified/found. My best guess is that the CUIT-Generator has a problem with the ItemTemplate - for whatever reason.

Comment: To follow up once you have a list view item... what children does it retrieve from a `GetChildren` call? Specifically, does it retrieve a control that your custom control is based on or only a custom? (also is your custom control inheriting from a standard control type?) Which, going back to my answer, if you implemented your match `CodedUi` object does it match the child of a specific `ListItem`?

Comment: sorry, got...distracted by another task. Anyway, my custom control derives from `UserControl`. Will answer the other inquiries later.

Comment: Being that `UserControl` is about fairly high on `WPF`'s control hierarchy, I wouldn't expect that type to be matched by `CodedUi`.